# microformat locations "relative" to site; how to publish full location but show only partial location

Tags: html, microformats

I am designing a new Information Architecture for some hospitality sites. I am using *microformats 2* for events and locations.

Most of the events published on a given site --*grandhotel.com* for example-- occur in spaces (rooms, courts...) --*Barcelona room in mezzanine level* for example-- in the same geographic location -- *The Grand Hotel at Great Street* for example-- so I just need to show the information of the space, as the hotel location is implied.

Some other events happen in outside locations, nearby restaurants or sport facilities --*Kings Crown Tennis Club* for example-- so I need to show the full location information.

So my problem is how to acomodate both scopes with both kinds of locations. I believe I always need to publish the full scope location information (for search engines, crawlers, extractors, aggregators) but only show the partial scope information for human visitors of the site.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: probably better asked on the microformats wiki